# Mocha MongoDB (Mongoose) tests hanging when run with Grunt

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gruntjs, mocha.js

I have a set of tests in the following format:

```
var mongoTest = require('../mongoTest.js');

//Connect to test DB before tests and disconnect after
before(function(done) {
    mongoTest.mongoConnect(done);
});

after(function(done) {
    mongoose.disconnect(done);
})

//Load Data Files
var testData = require('../testData.js')
var deviceAndLocationAnswers = testData.deviceAndLocationAnswers

//Repeated Functions:
var clearCollections = function(coll, callback) {
    mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection(coll.collectionName, 
        function(err, result) {
            callback();
        });
}

describe('Testing functions that use the Breakers collections', function(){
    //Test Setup
    var req = {query: {device: testData.powerConsumptionDevice}}

    before(function(done) {
        this.timeout(15000);
        async.forEach(mongoose.connection.collections, clearCollections, 
            function(err) {
                if (err) {console.log(err)};
                done();
            })
    });

    before(function(done) {
        this.timeout(15000);
        Breakers.create(testData.breakersData, function(err, model){
            done(err);
        });
    });

    after(function(done) {
        this.timeout(15000);
        async.forEach(mongoose.connection.collections, clearCollections, 
            function(err) {
                if (err) {console.log(err)};
                done();
            })
    });

    // Tests
    describe('Testing powerConsumption Function', function() {  
        it('Should produce some output', function(done) {
            this.timeout(15000);
            dbFunctions.powerConsumption(req, function(result) {
                result.should.exist;
                done();
            });
        });
        it('Should produce the same results as the mock up from testData', function(done) {
            this.timeout(15000);
            dbFunctions.powerConsumption(req, function(result) {
                result.should.be.deep.equal(testData.powerConsumptionResults);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

`mongoTest` comes from the following file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var dBaseURL = 'mongodb://xxxx:yyyyy@ds#####.mongolab.com:zzzz/myDB'; // details removed
exports.mongoConnect = function(callback) {
    mongoose.connect(dBaseURL, function(err) {
        if(err) {
        console.log('MongoDB Connection Error', err);
        } else {
            console.log('MongoDB Connection Successful')
        }
        callback();
    });
};
```

I also have another file where I've used mockgoose to mock out the database, and a third file of tests that just tests simple functions

These tests run successfully when I run them individually. But when I try and run all three with grunt, everything hangs on the first before call in one of the tests that deals with Mongo. No connection is made to the Mongo database. I can't even get info by placing a console.log() within the connect callback.

Here is the grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        // Configure a mochaTest task
        mochaTest: {
            jenkins: {
                options: {
                reporter: 'spec',
                captureFile: 'tests/results.txt', // Optionally capture the reporter output to a file
                quiet: false, // Optionally suppress output to standard out (defaults to false)
                clearRequireCache: true
                },
            src: ['tests/unit/*.js']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'mochaTest');
};
```

I've done a fresh install with NPM. The specific mechanism of my tests failing is the first `before` timing out after 30 seconds.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I feel like I've missed some key step, but I've been Googling for a solution for an hour with no luck. I've tried setting clear required cache to true and false, but neither option seems to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what particular interaction was causing my tests to fail, but they succeed if I separate the mocked and non-mocked tests into their own objects.

Here's the code that works:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        mochaTest: {
            unitTests: {
                options: {
                reporter: 'spec',
                captureFile: 'tests/unitTestResults.txt', // Optionally capture the reporter output to a file
                quiet: false, // Optionally suppress output to standard out (defaults to false)
                clearRequireCache: true
                },
            src: ['tests/unit/helpersTest.js', 'tests/unit/dbFunctionTests.js']
            }, mockedUnitTests: {
                options: {
                reporter: 'spec',
                captureFile: 'tests/mockedUnitTestResults.txt', // Optionally capture the reporter output to a file
                quiet: false, // Optionally suppress output to standard out (defaults to false)
                clearRequireCache: true
                },
            src: ['tests/unit/dbFunctionMockTests.js']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'mochaTest');
};
```